# Save to Cocos2dx UserDefault from the Cocos2dxActivity.java file?

Tags: cocos2d-x

My problem is rather simple, I can save to the "cocos2d::UserDefault" from iOS by doing this, because the .mm file can execute cpp easily:

```
cocos2d::UserDefault::getInstance()->setStringForKey("notification_payload", payload_string);
```

however on java i can't do this, so i was wondering if there is a simple cocos2dx method that can be used on java.

I know i might be able to execute cpp code from java by following this guide:

http://stnguyen.com/cocos2d-x/call-cpp-functions-from-java.html

But if possible i would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several hours of searching i found the answer.

Cocos2dx has a helper class to interact from java, the methods available from that class are listed here (this is for version 2.x but it worked in 3.x):

http://nigam.biz/cocos2dx/classorg_1_1cocos2dx_1_1lib_1_1_cocos2dx_helper.html

and an example of how they are implemented can be seen here (randomly found this on the internet, i don't think its an official documentation):

https://github.com/OiteBoys/Kunonekok/blob/master/kunonekonok/proj.android/src/org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxHelper.java

So the code i used is:

```
Cocos2dxHelper.setStringForKey("notification_payload","value");
```